# Управление известными сетями. Не удалось добавить сеть Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-10, wifi, пароль

При подключении к сети wi-fi, даже если установить галочку «подключаться автоматически», выбранная сеть не попадает в список известных сетей — Параметры → Сеть и интернет → Wi-Fi → Управление известными сетями.

В результате, после перезагрузки или отключения от сети, подключиться к ней без повторного ввода пароля не удается, вводить пароль требуется.

Какие действия можно предпринять, чтобы Windows снова запоминала пароли сетей Wi-Fi?

Предположительно, проблема появилась после глобального обновления релиза Windows 10.

Подходящей политики безопасности не нашлось.

Удалять устройства беспроводной связи пробовал.

Пользователь — Администратор.

Создавал другого пользователя (Администратора локального и сетевого) — проблема та же.

Беспроводные сети не запоминаются независимо от того, публичные они или частные.

При добавлении новой сети вручную в список «Управление известными сетями» получаю ошибку «Не удалось добавить новую сеть».

Версия Windows 10 — 1703, билд 15063.540, x64.
Беспроводные карточки RTL8723BE и теперь добавил RTL8192CU USB2.

UPD 14/09:
Выяснил опытным путем, что для сохранения беспроводной сети в список известных сетей не хватает прав. Пользователь входит в группу администраторов. Стало быть, какому-то файлу или папке нужно дать разрешения для Администраторов. Осталось выяснить, какую.

Comment: Напишите в поддержку Microsoft лучше. Даром что ль Windows столько денег стоит.

Comment: В поддержке есть такие рекомендации — Откатитесь назад вплоть до предыдущей версии Windows. Не один день лопатил форумы, люди не нашли ответов. Наверняка, какой-то компонент системы обращается с запросом на запись свойства и не получает прав на его изменение. Но понять, где и что мне нужно изменить (чему дать права на запись) — моих знаний не хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После неудачно проведенного конкурса на Стеке — ответ не найден, нескольких долгих переговоров со службой поддержки Microsoft и MSDN (это разные службы), пришли к совместному решению, что надо поставить Windows 10 с нуля.

Поставил с нуля. Проблема решилась =(

Answer (score 1):

Актуально и в 2021 году :-)

Появилась эта же проблема когда переставил Wi-Fi адаптер `TP-Link TL-WN781ND` в другой слот на материнской плате.

Мне помогло следующее:

1. Удалил все профили в `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces`
2. Дал разрешения `Полный доступ` для группы `Все` на директории `Wlansvc`, `Profiles`, `Interfaces`
3. Удалил все ветки в реестре в

   - `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\]`
   - `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged\]`
4. Перезагрузил и заново подключился к сети с установленой галочкой автоматического подключения.

*Windows 10 Корпоративная, x64, версия 1903, сборка 18362.295*

Answer (score -1):

попробуй следующее:
1.отключиться от сети wi-fi;
2.удалить свою сеть;
3.заново подключиться к сети. Вернуться в предыдущее меню "беспроводная сеть", пролистать вниз - там есть "Центр управления сетями и общим доступом".
4.жмешь на Подключение "Беспроводная сеть"  - Свойства беспроводной сети - ставишь галочку напротив "Подключаться автоматически, если сеть в радиусе действия".
5.перезагрузка ПК

Comment: прочитайте внимательнее «выбранная сеть не попадает в список известных сетей». нет возможности выполнить пункт 2, потому что список сетей пустой